# Create circle by tapping on google map , remove circle if user tap outside circle in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

[image]

I have to develop the above picture in android, which is already implemented in iOS.

Described below the functionality, initially map will be displayed in main activity.

**If user tap inside the circle circle will remain same, if user tap outside the circle the circle should be removed. If there is no circle on screen, now if user tap on the screen circle should be displayed again. If user zoom in/zoom out, the circle should be always in center.**

I draw the circle and making invisible if user clicks out side the circle. But **if I click just around the circle the onclicklistener is not called, instead camerachange listener called.**

This is my Activity class

```
      public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements OnMapReadyCallback,Response,OnMapClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    highlightMap(map,0x110000FF);
}


public static void highlightMap(final GoogleMap map, int fillColor) {

    if (map != null) {

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(getCoords(17.3700, 78.4800,map)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmap(17.3700,78.4800,fillColor)));
        options.alpha(1);

        final Marker marker = map.addMarker(options);
        marker.setDraggable(true);

        // I used this listener to make align the circle center
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition paramCameraPosition) {
                LatLng centerOfMap = map.getCameraPosition().target;
                marker.setPosition(centerOfMap);
            }
        });
    }
}


private static Bitmap getBitmap(double latitude, double longitude, int fillColor) {

    // fill color
    Paint paint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint1.setColor(fillColor);
    paint1.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    // stroke color
    Paint paint2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paint2.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    // circle radius - 200 meters
    int radius = 500;

    // create empty bitmap
    Bitmap b = Bitmap
            .createBitmap(radius * 2, radius * 2, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    c.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint1);
    c.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint2);

    return b;
}

private static LatLng getCoords(double lat, double lng,GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    Projection proj = map.getProjection();
    Point p = proj.toScreenLocation(latLng);
    p.set(p.x, p.y + 0);

    return proj.fromScreenLocation(p);
  }

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
    if(circleMarker.isVisible()){
        circleMarker.setVisible(false);
    }else{
        circleMarker.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This is my xml file

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.naveen.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/calndar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/citylifeLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cytilife_logo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sunLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="280dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sun" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Please let me know how can I identify if the user clicks inside/outside the circle which I drawn.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well I was thinking and I have an idea, well...
You create a Map.setOnMapClickListener
if there are a circle, and you click the map(out of the circle)... you remove/hidde the circle...

you need to use a var boolean to specify that there is a circle...

Circle circle;

```
if(mMap != null) {

  mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new
           GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick (LatLng latLng){

          if(circle!=null)
           {
              circle.remove();
              circle.setVisible(false);
            }else{
                circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
               .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
               .radius(10000)
               .strokeColor(Color.RED)
               .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
            }
        }
     });
```

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get your question properly, but still trying..
Can't you make a "faded" Imageview with match parent as height and width rover the map. 
And a circular transparent image set at the centreInParent. 
Then you can manage click on this circular imageview.

Can you post your code for mapClicklistner.

Comment: I should display google maps not faded image or some other @Harish Vats

Comment: I know. In your pic, map is shown faded, when Circle is displayed. 
Relative layout allows placing layout in pile one over another. 
So if faded view is placed over map,it can create similar effect.